# Amchart4 doesn't group data with same date

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, amcharts

As the title says, I am not able to group data with same date on date axis in Amchart4. In my example, I have 3 same dates with value 1, which should lead to 'sum' 3 but it looks like, that Amchart always takes last number of value in chart data array, which is 1. All required options should be set:

```
    dateAxis.groupData = true;
    ...
    series.dataFields.valueY = "value";
    ...
    series.groupFields.valueY = "sum";
```

I read through documentation and did not find any clue what could be wrong. I also tried many variations of chart settings but without any luck. I really do not know, what I am missing here.

CodePen Example:
https://codepen.io/Mari-n-Kusenda/pen/jOXgPYB?editors=1111